# [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113 when trying to install app on 64bit architecture

Tags: android, 64-bit

I am trying to migrate my project to 64 bit architecture.
I have followed the documentation about the subject and right now I am stuck when trying to use the following command that installs the app on my device, which is 64 bit -

```
adb install --abi arm64-v8a app-dev-debug.apk
```

I get the following error when trying to do so -

```
[INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113
```

I have tryed to search in multiple threads already opened here in stackoverflow but did not find any helpfull answer. I will try to be specific about what .so files I have in my project -

```
lib/armeabi-v7a/libARM_ARCH.so
lib/armeabi/libARM_ARCH.so
lib/x86/libARM_ARCH.so
```

if I understand correctly, none if my .so libraries were built for 64 bit architecture - if that is the case, how can I make them do support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because your app does not have 64-bit version of some lib. You can confirm that by building an apk then analyzing it by **Build > Analyze Apk...**

There you will see that no directory exists for 64-bit arch: x86_64, arm64_v8a

[image]

You need to provide native libs for these architecture to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

If you can see you dont have shared object for 64-bit architecture i.e(arm64-v8a). Make an arm64-v8a libARM_ARCH.so and place it at lib/armv64-v8a/libARM_ARCH.so .
Then your

`adb install --abi arm64-v8a app-dev-debug.apk`
will work on 64-bit devices

Comment: if I will replace it will it be compatible with 32 bit devices?

Comment: if I am using a 3rd party library from github my only chance would be to ask for a fix for this issue asap? or switch a library?

Comment: Yes. You can contact their support and ask about update to support 64-bit devices. Google Play has made it compulsory starting with August 2019 to provide 64-bit version of your app. All third party libs are releasing updates to fulfill this requirement.